# KivyMD without using kv file

Tags: python, kivymd

I'm trying to make an expense tracker app using KivyMD. I have built it already using kivy but it's design is awful, then i found out KivyMD and now i want to tweak the app using KivyMD but i want to do it without using a kv file because my app has a lot of nested if statements which are too complex to write in the kv file. Anyway, i'm trying to test KivyMD but running into this nasty ValueError
`ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions` and idk how to fix it without using a kv file. This question is asked plenty times but every answer uses a kv file. Can someone please help me understand this error and tackle it without kv. Thank you... Here is some code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.stacklayout import MDStackLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton, MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.metrics import dp,sp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
import re


#ALL SCREENS
class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
        box = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        b = MDRaisedButton(text="Content",size_hint = (1,0.5))
        box.add_widget(b)
        t = MDTextField(size_hint=(1,0.5))
        box.add_widget(t)
        self.add_widget(box)

#ScreenManager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
        

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepOrange"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Lime"
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

works perfectly fine when i remove the screenmanager and just return the MainScreen.
Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting `ScreenManager` stuff within method `build` and return it.

Comment: it's working now. So you're telling me that whatever needs to be returned (the root widget if you may) needs to be initialized inside the app class? Thanks again. You just keep coming through.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i have a question. My py file has a bunch of functions which manage the switching of screens, in kivy i used sm.current = "..."  to switch screens but that doesn't work in kivyMD since my screenmanager(sm) is defined in the App class n i can't refer it outside the class. i tried a bunch of things but nothing works. Could you please tell me where i should define these switch functions.

Comment: Have a look at [doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) for your first query. For second, can't say without seeing the actual implementation, but guessing that changing `sm` to `self.sm` might work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepOrange"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Lime"
        return screen_manager
```

Can you edit your code like this and try again?

Answer (score 0):

.py file

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
#importing the module to run the program
KV="""
MDScreen:
    Button:
        ...
        #your other widgets
""""
class My(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        #the below line helps in writing code within the python file.
        Builder.load_string(KV)
```